# How to enter search term in webpage search bar and click on a result url

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to work with VBA to text in cell B2 go out to webpage then search that text on the webpage and return the correct link. So item ABC goes out to www.something.com and in that search bar on that website it searches for ABC and returns the URL to click and load that site page only.

I have been searching the VBA return webpage, youtubed a bunch and can't find anything close.

```
Sub WindChill()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim location
    Dim button

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("http://wcprod.elliott-turbo.com/Windchill/app/")
        While ie.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

    Set location = .document.getElementById("location")
    Set button = .document.getElementById("btnContainer").Children(0)

    button.Click

    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    End With

    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will enter your search terms on the website and output the resulting URL to cell B3.
You will likely need to change the output based on your requirements.
Also it is highly recommended to use **Option Explicit** in VBA and add **Microsoft Internet Controls** and **Microsoft HTML Object Library** to your project references instead of using CreateObject.

```
    Sub WindChill()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim location as Object
    Dim button as Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("http://wcprod.elliott-turbo.com/Windchill/app/")
        While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend

    Set location = .Document.getElementById("location")
    Set button = .Document.getElementById("btnContainer").Children(0)

    'Assign value to searchbar and click search button
    location.Value = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value
    Call button.Click

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    'Assign resulting LocationURL hyperlink in B3, can be adjusted based on requirements
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value = .LocationURL
    Call Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B3"), .LocationURL)

    End With

    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```